# Random error when reading memory

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that involves memory reading, and sometimes it has a problem when trying to read memory. The debugger tells me the error is in the IF condition, so I think my problem is a random value that memory acquire (maybe something with letters, and since i'm trying to read integers it crash?)

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(mem3.ReadPointer(address3)) >= 1 && Convert.ToInt32(mem3.ReadPointer(address3)) <= 100)
    label5.Text = "LVL " + mem3.ReadPointer(address3).ToString();
```

My question, is there a way for skipping code (in this case the if) if a value is out of range?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `TryParse` instead.. if that is indeed your issue (playing with random memory though.. its hard to tell what the problem may be without more context):

```
int val;
if (int.TryParse(mem3.ReadPointer(address3), out val)) {
    // all good, continue using val
    if (val >= 1 && val <= 100) // ...
}
else {
    // failed conversion
}
```

If you're running on a 64-bit machine though.. you're probably wanting to store the pointer value in a `long` instead of an `int`... so it doesn't overflow.

EDIT:

What does `ReadPointer` return? An integral memory address or a value at the address? Now that I've re-read your question I'm not entirely sure what you're after (but I'll keep this here just in case).

Comment: My pointer converted to int returns the value of the pointed address. Thanks for the code, I will try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Alright, instead of crashing, i'm just getting "A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException ocurred..." in debug console, so I think that the code you gave me solves the crash.

Comment: There is nothing in what you've provided here that would cause that. So I guess this solves your _first_ problem :)

Comment: Woops, I did wrong, problem wasnt solved. 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll' in the tryparse line.

Comment: Okay. Store the result of ReadPointer in a variable before TryParse. What happens? What type is that variable?